# Netty 5 sending JSON POST request

Tags: json, http, post, netty

I'm trying to send JSON content to the remote endpoint as a POST request over HTTPS using Netty 5.0.0.Alpha2. My problem is that the new API doesn't seem to offer a way of simply setting the JSON content as the request body without using an `HttpPostRequestEncoder` object and specifying a name for the JSON attribute. Is it possible to set the content "anonymously", and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the request successfully by using the concrete `DefaultFullHttpRequest` handle instead of the `HttpRequest` interface. The code now looks a bit like this (edited for brevity):

```
DefaultFullHttpRequest request = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "/path/to/x");
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaderValues.GZIP + "," + HttpHeaderValues.DEFLATE);
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.ACCEPT, "application/json");
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.HOST, "somehost.com:443");
ByteBuf buffer = request.content().clear();
int p0 = buffer.writerIndex();
buffer.writeBytes(json.getBytes());
int p1 = buffer.writerIndex();
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(p1 - p0));
```

I'm sure this could be prettier (in particular the content-length calculation), but it seems to work and saves anyone wasting any brain cycles on this question.

Thanks if you happened to consider it.